# Conditions in Spatial Joins of QGIS?

Tags: qgis, spatial-join

I'm just starting to get my head around writing simple expressions in QGIS. I have 2 polygon layers: the first shows the boundaries of houses of various types and how many people live in each. The second shows the boundaries of zones which group certain houses together.

I would like the second layer to show a summary of how many people live in each type of house in that zone. I also need the values to update automatically should i make changes to the first layer. For this i reckon that the second layer will need a different field for each house type and that these fields should be virtual.

I have gotten as far as downloading the Reffunctions plugin and getting the intersecting_geom_sum function to add up all of the people in each zone. However, i am struggling to introduce the condition whereby each field only adds the values of a specific type.

Answer (score 3):

you also can use a virtual layer together with a group statement, something like:

```
   SELECT zones.geometry, zones.typ, houses.typ, sum(houses.habs) as sumHabs
   FROM zones LEFT Join houses
   ON st_intersects(houses.geometry, zones.geometry)
   group by zones.geometry, zones.typ, houses.typ
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new virtual field to the **house** layer called NumRes_Type1. If the house is house type 1, this field will be the number of residents in the house. Otherwise it will be 0. Use this function, substituting the correct field names:

> if("house_type" = house type 1, "number_of_residents", 0)

Repeat for each house type. Now you have fields in the house layer called NumRes_Type1, NumRes_Type2, NumRes_Type3, etc.

Now use the fields you just created with the intersecting_geom_sum function to add up the number of residents of each house type. Add a virtual layer to the **zones** layer with this function:

> intersecting_geom_sum('house_layer', 'NumRes_Type1')

Comment: If there's any issue with these functions, try using double quotes around the field name in the intersecting_geom_sum functions. Seems like it should be double quotes, but the syntax and example given with this function used single quotes.